# Covering a family of sets of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ with boxes of a given diameter

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, integer-lattices, statistical-mechanics

Let $diam(A)$ be the graph distance between the two farthest vertices contained in a finite set $A \subset \mathbb{Z}^d$. Is it true that there exists a real $\eta(d)>0$  such that for any finite $A \subset \mathbb{Z}^d$, it is possible to cover $A$ with a box of diameter $\eta \cdot diam(A)$?

If yes, what is the minimal $\eta$?

If not, which restrictions should we impose on the family of sets $A$ in order this to be true?

Comment: Is $d$ fixed here?  Do you want to try to find an $\eta$ for each $d$ or do you want to (try to) find an $\eta$ that works for each $d$?

Comment: The value $\eta$ might depend on $d$.